# Simplest way to throw an error/exception with a custom message in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to do something in Swift that I'm used to doing in multiple other languages:  throw a runtime exception with a custom message.  For example (in Java):

```
throw new RuntimeException("A custom message here")
```

I understand that I can throw enum types that conform to the ErrorType protocol, but I don't want to have to define enums for every type of error I throw.  Ideally, I'd like to be able mimic the example above as closely as possible.  I looked into creating a custom class that implements the [ErrorType protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_ErrorType_Protocol/index.html), but I can't even figure out that what that protocol requires.  Ideas?

Comment: Swift 2 throw/catch are not exceptions.

Answer (score 291, accepted):

The simplest approach is probably to define *one* custom `enum` with just one `case` that has a `String` attached to it:

```
enum MyError: Error {
    case runtimeError(String)
}
```

Example usage would be something like:

```
func someFunction() throws {
    throw MyError.runtimeError("some message")
}
do {
    try someFunction()
} catch MyError.runtimeError(let errorMessage) {
    print(errorMessage)
}
```

If you wish to use existing `Error` types, the most general one would be an `NSError`, and you could make a factory method to create and throw one with a custom message.

Comment: Hi, I know it's been a year you posted this answer, but I would like to know if it's possible to get the `String` inside your `errorMessage`, if so, how do I do that?

Comment: @RenanCamaforte I'm sorry, I don't understand the question? The `String` is associated here with the `MyError.RuntimeError` (set at the time of `throw`), and you gain access to it at the `catch` (with `let errorMessage`).

Comment: You were asked for the simpliest solution. Solution when you create custom enums, functions and etc is not simple. I know at least one way but I won't post it there because it is for objective-C

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov If you don’t know a simpler way for Swift, which was also specified in the question, then this would be the _simplest_ way, even of you don’t consider it simple in a more general context that would include Objective-C. (Also, this answer is basically a one-line one-time definition of an enum, the function and its call is an example of usage, not part of the solution.)

Comment: @Arkku
answered

Comment: It is highly recommended that you avoid using the forced - `try` expression in production code since it can cause a runtime error and cause your application to crash.

Comment: @Otar Yes, but… you are talking about `try!`, which isn't used here. You indeed can't even make the potentially throwing call without some kind of `try`. (Also that part of the code is the example usage, not the actual solution.)

Answer (score 209):

The simplest way is to make `String` conform to `Error`:

```
extension String: Error {}
```

Then you can just throw a string:

```
throw "Some Error"
```

To make the string itself be the `localizedString` of the error you can instead extend `LocalizedError`:

```
extension String: LocalizedError {
    public var errorDescription: String? { return self }
}
```

Comment: This is clever, but is there a way to make its `localizedDescription` be the string itself?

Comment: Elegant indeed! But it breaks down for me in test targets with the following message `Redundant conformance of 'String' to protocol 'Error'` :(

Comment: @Akku My problem with String as an Error is that it is intended to be used for untyped exceptions with identical handling. This is unlikely a sound case in the real world. Nevertheless ingenious answer.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work for me. Says it can't complete the operation when parsing `error.localizedDescription` after throwing a string.

Comment: Warning: this extension caused problems for me with external libraries. [Here's my example](https://github.com/google/promises/issues/88#issuecomment-572838985). This is possible for any 3rd party library that manages Errors; I would avoid extensions that make String conform to Error.

Comment: A protocol should declare what a type "is", not what it "might be". A string is not always an error, and this extension makes it easy to accidentally assume that it is, defeating type safety.

Comment: @dbplunkett I don't think this is violates that rule. One thing strings are capable of is providing a a description of themselves. Marking them as capable of doing so doesn't seem misleading. They can ALWAYS do it, it's not dependent on circumstance.

Answer (score 50):

@nick-keets's solution is most elegant, but it did break down for me in test target with the following compile time error:

`Redundant conformance of 'String' to protocol 'Error'`

Here's another approach:

```swift
struct RuntimeError: LocalizedError {
    let description: String

    init(_ description: String) {
        self.description = description
    }

    var errorDescription: String? {
        description
    }
}
```

And to use:

```
throw RuntimeError("Error message.")
```

**Important**: Updated to use `LocalizedError` instead of `Error`. Using `Error` and overriding `localizedDescription` will **NOT** return a correct description. Instead, it will look like this: `The operation couldn’t be completed. (__lldb_expr_39.RuntimeError error 1.)`

Answer (score 43):

**Swift 4:**

As per:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nserror

if you don't want to define a custom exception, you could use a standard NSError object as follows:

```
import Foundation

do {
  throw NSError(domain: "my error domain", code: 42, userInfo: ["ui1":12, "ui2":"val2"] ) 
}
catch let error as NSError {
  print("Caught NSError: \(error.localizedDescription), \(error.domain), \(error.code)")
  let uis = error.userInfo 
  print("\tUser info:")
  for (key,value) in uis {
    print("\t\tkey=\(key), value=\(value)")
  }
}
```

Prints:

```
Caught NSError: The operation could not be completed, my error domain, 42
    User info:
        key=ui1, value=12
        key=ui2, value=val2
```

This allows you to provide a custom string (the error domain), plus a numeric code and a dictionary with all the additional data you need, of any type.

N.B.: this was tested on OS=Linux (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).

Comment: It seems outside the API intent to pass "my error description" to a parameter called `domain`.

Comment: The fix highlights a second problem: The catch block has `error.localizedDescription`, but that description doesn't get set to anything in the throw statement. So you end up with just a generic "The operation could not be completed" error.

Comment: @EdwardBrey it was left for illustration purposes only, there are plenty other fields that the user can customize.

Comment: Event with `error.localizedDescription` I get the domain and the code from NSError. In console I see a message that follows this pattern `The operation couldn’t be completed. (\(domain) error \(code).)`. This looks good to me, thank you PJ for sharing this

Comment: I added an answer that uses `NSLocalizedDescriptionKey` in the `userInfo` dictionary, which is the documented way to provide the message string.

Answer (score 21):

Check this cool version out. The idea is to implement both String and ErrorType protocols and use the error's rawValue.

```
enum UserValidationError: String, Error {
  case noFirstNameProvided = "Please insert your first name."
  case noLastNameProvided = "Please insert your last name."
  case noAgeProvided = "Please insert your age."
  case noEmailProvided = "Please insert your email."
}
```

Usage:

```
do {
  try User.define(firstName,
                  lastName: lastName,
                  age: age,
                  email: email,
                  gender: gender,
                  location: location,
                  phone: phone)
}
catch let error as User.UserValidationError {
  print(error.rawValue)
  return
}
```

Comment: There seems to be little benefit in this approach, as you still need the `as User.UserValidationError` and on top of that the `.rawValue`. However, if you instead implemented `CustomStringConvertible` as `var description: String { return rawValue }`, it might be useful to get the custom descriptions using the enum syntax without having to go through `rawValue` in every place where you print it.

Comment: better implement localizedDescription method to return .rawValue

Answer (score 17):

Simplest solution without extra extensions, enums, classes and etc.:

```
NSException(name:NSExceptionName(rawValue: "name"), reason:"reason", userInfo:nil).raise()
```

Comment: re. your comments on my answer, this is simple only in the sense that you have somewhat arbitrarily decided that defining and enum or extension _once_ is complicated. So, yes, your answer has zero lines of "setup", but at the cost of having _every_ thrown exception be a complicated and non-Swiftlike (`raise()` instead of `throw`) spell that is hard to remember. Compare your solution with `throw Foo.Bar("baz")` or `throw "foo"` multiplied by the number of places where an exception is thrown – IMO the one-time fee of one-line extension or enum is far preferable to things like `NSExceptionName`.

Comment: @Arkku For example `postNotification` requires 2-3 params and its selector is similar to this one. Do you override `Notification` and/or `NotificationCenter` in each project to allow it to accept less input params?

Comment: No, and I wouldn't even use the solution in my own answer; I only posted it to answer the question, not because it is something I would do myself. Anyway, that is besides the point: I stand by the opinion that your answer is by far more complicated _to use_ than either mine or Nick Keets's. Of course there are other valid points to consider, such as if extending `String` to conform to `Error` is too surprising, or if a `MyError` enum is too vague (personally I would answer yes to both, and instead do a separate enum case for each error, i.e., `throw ThisTypeOfError.thisParticularCase`).

Answer (score 9):

In case you don't need to catch the error and you want to immediately stop the application you can use a fatalError:
    `fatalError ("Custom message here")`

Comment: Note that this will not throw an error which can be caught. This will crash the app.

Answer (score 7):

Based on @Nick keets answer, here is a more complete example:

```
extension String: Error {} // Enables you to throw a string

extension String: LocalizedError { // Adds error.localizedDescription to Error instances
    public var errorDescription: String? { return self }
}

func test(color: NSColor) throws{
    if color == .red {
        throw "I don't like red"
    }else if color == .green {
        throw "I'm not into green"
    }else {
        throw "I like all other colors"
    }
}

do {
    try test(color: .green)
} catch let error where error.localizedDescription == "I don't like red"{
    Swift.print ("Error: \(error)") // "I don't like red"
}catch let error {
    Swift.print ("Other cases: Error: \(error.localizedDescription)") // I like all other colors
}
```

Originally published on my swift blog: http://eon.codes/blog/2017/09/01/throwing-simple-errors/

Comment: TBH: I now just do `throw NSError(message: "err", code: 0)`

Comment: So you don't even use your own example? :D

Oh, and the first argument should be `domain`, not `message`, right?

Comment: Your right, domain. And no, adds too much sugar in the code. I usually make alot of small frameworks and modules and try to keep convenient extension sugar low. These days I try to use a mix between Result and NSError

Comment: `catch let error where error.localizedDescription == "I don't like red"` is brittle, this would be a good candidate for a strongly typed error enum. And another solution here showed potential issues when conforming `String` to `Error` globally.

Answer (score 4):

First, let's see few usage examples, then how to make those samples work (Definition).

### Usage

```swift
do {
    throw MyError.Failure
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Or more specific style:

```swift
do {
    try somethingThatThrows()
} catch MyError.Failure {
    // Handle special case here.
} catch MyError.Rejected {
    // Another special case...
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Also, categorization is possible:

```swift
do {
    // ...
} catch is MyOtherErrorEnum {
    // If you handle entire category equally.
} catch let error as MyError {
    // Or handle few cases equally (without string-compare).
    switch error {
    case .Failure:
        fallthrough;
    case .Rejected:
        myShowErrorDialog(error);
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

### Definition

```
public enum MyError: String, LocalizedError {
    case Failure = "Connection fail - double check internet access."
    case Rejected = "Invalid credentials, try again."
    case Unknown = "Unexpected REST-API error."

    public var errorDescription: String? { self.rawValue }
}
```

### Pros and Cons

Swift defines `error` variable automatically, and a handler only needs to read `localizedDescription` property.

But that is vague, and we should use "`catch MyError.Failure {}`" style instead (to be clear about what-case we handle), although, categorization is possible as shown in usage example.

1. [Teodor-Ciuraru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38834987/8740349) (which's almost equal) still needs a long manual cast (like "`catch let error as User.UserValidationError { ... }`").
2. The [accepted categorization-enum approach's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31443717/8740349) disadvantages:

   - Is too vague as he comments himself, so that catchers may need to compare `String` message!? (just to know exact error).
   - For throwing same more than once, needs copy/pasting message!!
   - Also, needs a long phrase as well, like "`catch MyError.runtimeError(let errorMessage) { ... }`".
3. The [NSException approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49831576/8740349) has same disadvantages of categorization-enum approach (except maybe shorter catching paragraph), also, even if put in a factory method to create and throw, is quite complicated.

### Conclusion

This completes other existing solutions, by simply using `LocalizedError` instead of `Error`, and hopefully saves someone from reading all other posts like me.

(My laziness sometimes causes me a lot of work.)

### Testing

```swift
import Foundation
import XCTest
@testable import MyApp

class MyErrorTest: XCTestCase {
    func testErrorDescription_beSameAfterThrow() {
        let obj = MyError.Rejected;
        let msg = "Invalid credentials, try again."
        XCTAssertEqual(obj.rawValue, msg);
        XCTAssertEqual(obj.localizedDescription, msg);
        do {
            throw obj;
        } catch {
            XCTAssertEqual(error.localizedDescription, msg);
        }
    }

    func testThrow_triggersCorrectCatch() {
        // Specific.
        var caught = "None"
        do {
            throw MyError.Rejected;
        } catch MyError.Failure {
            caught = "Failure"
        } catch MyError.Rejected {
            caught = "Successful reject"
        } catch {
            caught = "Default"
        }
        XCTAssertEqual(caught, "Successful reject");
    }
}
```

### Other tools:

**#1** If implementing `errorDescription` for each `enum` is a pain, then implement it once for all, like:

```swift
extension RawRepresentable where RawValue == String, Self: LocalizedError {
    public var errorDescription: String? {
        return self.rawValue;
    }
}
```

> Above only adds logic to enums that already extend `LocalizedError` (but one could remove "`Self: LocalizedError`" part, to make it apply to any string-enum).

**#2** What if we need additional context, like `FileNotFound` with file-path associated? see my other post for that:

[https://stackoverflow.com/a/70448052/8740349](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31443645/simplest-way-to-throw-an-error-exception-with-a-custom-message-in-swift#70448052)

> Basically, copy and add `LocalizedErrorEnum` from above link into your project once, and reuse as many times as required with associative-enums.

Comment: d= (◕‿↼ ) For anyone who doesn't like copy/paste (or thinks extensions could conflict later).

Answer (score 3):

I like @Alexander-Borisenko's answer, but the localized description was not returned when caught as an Error. It seems that you need to use LocalizedError instead:

```
struct RuntimeError: LocalizedError
{
    let message: String

    init(_ message: String)
    {
        self.message = message
    }

    public var errorDescription: String?
    {
        return message
    }
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39176551/2715107) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Throwing code should make clear whether the error message is appropriate for display to end users or is only intended for developer debugging. To indicate a description is displayable to the user, I use a struct `DisplayableError` that implements the `LocalizedError` protocol.

```swift
struct DisplayableError: Error, LocalizedError {
    let errorDescription: String?

    init(_ description: String) {
        errorDescription = description
    }
}
```

Usage for throwing:

```
throw DisplayableError("Out of pixie dust.")
```

Usage for display:

```
let messageToDisplay = error.localizedDescription
```

Answer (score 2):

First, let's see `LocalizedErrorEnum`'s usage examples, then how to make those samples work (in Sorce-code section).

### Usage

```
do {
    let path = "/my/path/to/file.txt";
    throw MyErrorCategory.FileNotFound(
        atPath: path
    );
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Failed to find file. {
  atPath: /my/path/to/file.txt
}
```

**Definition:**

```swift
public enum MyErrorCategory: LocalizedErrorEnum {
    case FileNotFound(String = "Failed to find file.", atPath: String)
    case Connection(String = "Connection fail - double check internet access.")
}
```

> The first argument is treated as message (in `LocalizedErrorEnum` enum).

### Features required <sup>(background)</sup>

**#1 Firstly,** I want messages without copy/pasting, and that with ability to `catch` a group of different error-cases, without listing each-case (solution, `enum` is pretty unique without copy/paste need, and each enum can be considered another group).

**#2 Secondly,** some errors like "FileNotFound" need to have variable context/details, like for file-path (but Raw-Value `enum` does not support instance-variables, and unlike **#1**, the *built-in* `enum` is not the solution).

**#3 Lastly,** I want to be able to catch each case separately, NOT catching entire `struct` and/or `class` then doing `switch` inside the `catch`, and want to avoid forgeting the rethrow of cases we don't handle.

### Source-code <sup>(solution meeting requirements)</sup>

Simply, copy and add `LocalizedErrorEnum` from below into your project once, and reuse as many times as required with associative-enums.

```
public protocol LocalizedErrorEnum: LocalizedError {
    var errorDescription: String? { get }
}

extension LocalizedErrorEnum {
    public var errorDescription: String? {
        if let current = Mirror(reflecting: self).children.first {
            let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: current.value);
            // Initial error description.
            let message = mirror.children.first?.value as? String
                ?? current.label ?? "Unknown-case";
            var context = "";
            // Iterate additional context.
            var i = 0;
            for associated in mirror.children {
                if i >= 1 {
                    if let text = associated.value as? String {
                        context += "\n  ";
                        if let label: String = associated.label {
                            context += "\(label): "
                        }
                        context += text;
                    }
                }
                i += 1;
            }
            return context.isEmpty ? message : (
                message + " {" + context + "\n}"
            );
        }
        return "\(self)";
    }
}
```

> **Note** that as mentioned on my profile, using above code under Apache 2.0 license is allowed as well (without attribution need).
>
> See also [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31443645/simplest-way-to-throw-an-error-exception-with-a-custom-message-in-swift#68091816) if you don't need additional context-variable with error (or for a comparison with other approaches).

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest a variation of some of the proposed solutions:

```swift
public enum MyError: Error {
    var localizedDescription: String {
        get {
            switch(self) {
                case .network(let message, let code):
                    return "\(message) (\(code))"
                case .invalidInput(message: let message):
                    return message
            }
        }
    }
    case network(message: String, code: Int)
    case invalidInput(message: String)
}
```

It's a little more work to create but it provides the best of all worlds:

- It's an `enum` so it can be used in a `switch` statement.
- All the errors must be created with a message that can be a different one even for the same types of error (unlike enums that extend `String`)
- It provides the message under the `localizedDescription` that every developer is expecting.

Comment: If the majority of the cases just have a message, is there a way to simplify the switch statement with a default case?

Answer (score 1):

*To reiterate @pj-finnegan's answer, several people's comments, and the footnote of the accepted answer…*

I prefer several other answers provided here (if i'm looking for best practices). But if **I'm answering** the question as asked, the **simplest** way to do this (IFF you are are in iOS/macOS/…) is to used the bridged type `NSError`. *(This question is tagged with `iOS`, so we can assume this is present.)*

```
func myFunction(meNoLikey:Bool) throws {
    guard meNoLikey == false else {
        throw NSError(domain: "SubsystemOfMyApp", code: 99, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "My Message!"] )
    }
    // safe to carry on…
}
```

You can decide to have meaningful domains or codes, or not. The `userInfo` key `NSLocalizedDescriptionKey` is the only thing needed to deliver the message you request.

Look up `NSError.UserInfoKey` for any additional details you want to provide in the userInfo. You can also add anything you want, if you would like to deliver details to anyone catching the error.

Answer (score -1):

Usually I would model `Error` using enum. But for the simplest way of constructing `Error`s, I use old good `NSError`s.
Sometimes I have no time to think upfront and design structured error, sometimes it is just of no use since other code uses `NSError`s (especially if it not only throws them, but **expects** `NSError`s when consuming them from your code). `NSError` is potentially capable of adopting `LocalizedError` protocol.

I add a convenience init to `NSError`.

```
extension NSError {
        
    /// Create `NSError` that is potentially compatible with  `LocalizedError`.
    /// Parameter string literals can be extracted and localized with Xcode build-in tools.
    @available(macOS 13, iOS 16, tvOS 16, watchOS 9, *)
    public convenience init(domain: String = #file, code: Int = Int(#line), description: LocalizedStringResource? = nil, failureReason: LocalizedStringResource? = nil, recoverySuggestion: LocalizedStringResource? = nil, helpAnchor: LocalizedStringResource? = nil) {
        var userInfo = [String : Any]()
        
        if let description {
            userInfo[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = String(localized: description)
        }
        
        if let failureReason {
            userInfo[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = String(localized: failureReason)
        }
        
        if let recoverySuggestion {
            userInfo[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = String(localized: recoverySuggestion)
        }
        
        if let helpAnchor {
            userInfo[NSHelpAnchorErrorKey] = String(localized: helpAnchor)
        }
        
        self.init(domain: domain, code: code, userInfo: userInfo.isEmpty ? nil : userInfo)
    }
}
```

With that small piece of code in project now anywhere in my code I can just:

```
throw error = NSError(description: "Error message to localise.")
// Or in more verbose way.
throw error = NSError(description: "Error message to localise.", failureReason: "FailureReason")
```

What's interesting is that when I create NSErrors in such way their string literals are automatically parsed with Xcode and become ready ready for localization.

This approach makes errors created this ready to **indeed** conform to `LocalizedError`.

In simplest form without messing with subtypes it can be done just as easy:

```
extension NSError: LocalizedError {
    
    public var errorDescription: String? { localizedDescription }
    
    public var failureReason: String? { localizedFailureReason }
    
    public var recoverySuggestion: String? { localizedRecoverySuggestion }
    
    // public var helpAnchor: String? { get }  // Goes as is.
}
```

On previous systems such approach can also work, but it would require wrapping parameters into `NSLocalizedString()` if you want them translated in the end.
There is a [small SPM called NSErrorExtension](https://github.com/Mrteller/NSErrorExtension) to make the code work for older versions of platforms.