# How to provide a localized description with an Error type in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift3, error-handling, nslocalizedstring

I am defining a custom error type with Swift 3 syntax and I want to provide a user-friendly description of the error which is returned by the `localizedDescription` property of the `Error` object. How can I do it?

```
public enum MyError: Error {
  case customError

  var localizedDescription: String {
    switch self {
    case .customError:
      return NSLocalizedString("A user-friendly description of the error.", comment: "My error")
    }
  }
}

let error: Error = MyError.customError
error.localizedDescription
// "The operation couldn’t be completed. (MyError error 0.)"
```

Is there a way for the `localizedDescription` to return my custom error description ("A user-friendly description of the error.")? Note that the error object here is of type `Error` and not `MyError`. I can, of course, cast the object to MyError

```
(error as? MyError)?.localizedDescription
```

but is there a way to make it work without casting to my error type?

Answer (score 583, accepted):

As described in the Xcode 8 beta 6 release notes,

> Swift-defined error types can provide localized error descriptions by adopting the new LocalizedError protocol.

In your case:

```
public enum MyError: Error {
    case customError
}

extension MyError: LocalizedError {
    public var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {
        case .customError:
            return NSLocalizedString("A user-friendly description of the error.", comment: "My error")
        }
    }
}

let error: Error = MyError.customError
print(error.localizedDescription) // A user-friendly description of the error.
```

You can provide even more information if the error is converted
to `NSError` (which is always possible):

```
extension MyError : LocalizedError {
    public var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {
        case .customError:
            return NSLocalizedString("I failed.", comment: "")
        }
    }
    public var failureReason: String? {
        switch self {
        case .customError:
            return NSLocalizedString("I don't know why.", comment: "")
        }
    }
    public var recoverySuggestion: String? {
        switch self {
        case .customError:
            return NSLocalizedString("Switch it off and on again.", comment: "")
        }
    }
}

let error = MyError.customError as NSError
print(error.localizedDescription)        // I failed.
print(error.localizedFailureReason)      // Optional("I don\'t know why.")
print(error.localizedRecoverySuggestion) // Optional("Switch it off and on again.")
```

By adopting the `CustomNSError` protocol the error can provide
a `userInfo` dictionary (and also a `domain` and `code`). Example:

```
extension MyError: CustomNSError {

    public static var errorDomain: String {
        return "myDomain"
    }

    public var errorCode: Int {
        switch self {
        case .customError:
            return 999
        }
    }

    public var errorUserInfo: [String : Any] {
        switch self {
        case .customError:
            return [ "line": 13]
        }
    }
}

let error = MyError.customError as NSError

if let line = error.userInfo["line"] as? Int {
    print("Error in line", line) // Error in line 13
}

print(error.code) // 999
print(error.domain) // myDomain
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you make `MyError` an `Error` first and extend it with  `LocalizedError` later? Is there a difference if you made it a `LocalizedError` in the first place?

Comment: @Gee.E: It makes no difference. It is just a way to organize the code (one extension for each protocol). Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36263892/extensions-in-my-own-custom-class, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40502086/how-to-properly-use-class-extensions-in-swift, or https://www.natashatherobot.com/using-swift-extensions/.

Comment: Ah, check. I get what you're saying now. The "Protocol Conformance" section on https://www.natashatherobot.com/using-swift-extensions/ is indeed a good example of what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinR If my error would be converted to NSError how can I pass a dictionary from error that can be accessed as NSError's userInfo ?

Comment: Beware to type `var errorDescription: String?` instead of **`String`**. There is a bug in the implementation of LocalizedError. See [SR-5858](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5858).

Comment: Shouldn't you still get `localizedDescription` even if you don't implement `public var errorDescription: String?`. [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/localizederror) say it has a default implementation. However when I do `print(error.localizedDescription)` I get **The operation couldn’t be completed** error from the compiler. Doing `print(error)` is fine

Comment: Thanks! [Undocumented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/error/2292912-localizeddescription) magic is always fun to work out, so answers like this are a huge help.

Comment: Just how do all these work? I mean the variable name we use to log is different from the variable name that we actually wrote the value in. It must be a read-only computed property that we're accessing right?

Comment: @Honey: There is a lot of “magic” in the Error<->NSError bridging, compare https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0112-nserror- bridging.md. The implementation (I think) is in https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/NSError.swift.

Comment: Updated link from @MartinR's comment: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0112-nserror-bridging.md

Comment: @ethanhuang13 Even though it's filed as a bug, it doesn't count as a bug. LocalizedError requires the type of `errorDescription` to be `String?`, not `String`. Otherwise, the default implementation ("The operation couldn’t be completed") will be provided. With that said, I appreciate you pointing that out; I've made that mistake myself multiple times.

Comment: @Honey "The operation couldn’t be completed" **IS** the default implementation of `localizedDescription` when you either don't implement `errorDescription` or it returns `nil`.

Answer (score 63):

I would also add, if your error has parameters like this

```
enum NetworkError: LocalizedError {
  case responseStatusError(status: Int, message: String)
}
```

you can call these parameters in your localized description like this:

```
extension NetworkError {
  public var errorDescription: String? {
    switch self {
    case let .responseStatusError(status, message):
      return "Error with status \(status) and message \(message) was thrown"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

There are now two Error-adopting protocols that your error type can adopt in order to provide additional information to Objective-C — LocalizedError and CustomNSError. Here's an example error that adopts both of them:

```
enum MyBetterError : CustomNSError, LocalizedError {
    case oops

    // domain
    static var errorDomain : String { return "MyDomain" }
    // code
    var errorCode : Int { return -666 }
    // userInfo
    var errorUserInfo: [String : Any] { return ["Hey":"Ho"] };

    // localizedDescription
    var errorDescription: String? { return "This sucks" }
    // localizedFailureReason
    var failureReason: String? { return "Because it sucks" }
    // localizedRecoverySuggestion
    var recoverySuggestion: String? { return "Give up" }

}
```

Comment: Can you make an edit? Your examples don't help much to understand the value of each. Or just delete it because MartinR's answer offers this exactly...

Answer (score 11):

This one worked for me:

```
NSError(domain: "com.your", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Error description"])
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a struct can be an alternative. A little bit elegance with static localization:

```
import Foundation

struct MyError: LocalizedError, Equatable {

   private var description: String!

   init(description: String) {
       self.description = description
   }

   var errorDescription: String? {
       return description
   }

   public static func ==(lhs: MyError, rhs: MyError) -> Bool {
       return lhs.description == rhs.description
   }
}

extension MyError {

   static let noConnection = MyError(description: NSLocalizedString("No internet connection",comment: ""))
   static let requestFailed = MyError(description: NSLocalizedString("Request failed",comment: ""))
}

func throwNoConnectionError() throws {
   throw MyError.noConnection
}

do {
   try throwNoConnectionError()
}
catch let myError as MyError {
   switch myError {
   case .noConnection:
       print("noConnection: \(myError.localizedDescription)")
   case .requestFailed:
       print("requestFailed: \(myError.localizedDescription)")
   default:
      print("default: \(myError.localizedDescription)")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is more elegant solution:

```
  enum ApiError: String, LocalizedError {

    case invalidCredentials = "Invalid credentials"
    case noConnection = "No connection"

    var localizedDescription: String { return NSLocalizedString(self.rawValue, comment: "") }

  }
```

Comment: This may be more elegant at runtime, but the static localization step will fail to extract these strings for translators; you'll see a `"Bad entry in file – Argument is not a literal string"` error when you run `exportLocalizations` or `genstrings` to create your list of translatable text.

Comment: @savinola agree, static localization will not work in such case. Perhaps using `switch + case` is only option...

Comment: Using raw values will also prevent the use of associated values for any of your errors

Answer (score 1):

```html
enum NetworkError: LocalizedError {
    case noConnection

    public var description: String {
    ///You can switch self here if you have multiple cases.
        return "No internet connection"
    }

    // You need to implement `errorDescription`, not `localizedDescription`.
    public var errorDescription: String? {
        return description
    }
}
```