# Swift 3 errors with additional data

Tags: swift, error-handling, swift3

In Swift 3, what is the recommended way to put (potentially lots of) additional information in an error/exception that the catcher can use to solve/handle the problem? In all the examples I've seen, they use `enum`s with associated values, and that seems overly cumbersome/verbose for lots of information.

Specifically, I am writing a simple parser and want a place to store the affected line and column numbers (and potentially other information in the future), but without requiring that every handler explicitly declare those as associated values, as that would be a burden on the caller.

At this point I can basically see two ways of doing this, neither of which seems particularly elegant and both of which require defining two different things:

1. Define an outer `enum` error that represents the type of error, and for each case accept a parameter that is an object that contains the additional exception details, or
2. Use the object as the actual `Error` and pass in a case from an `enum` to its constructor to represent the actual error condition.

Both of these feel somewhat unclean to me though as they take two separate concepts to represent a simple idea, an error, and I'm just wondering if there's a nicer way to do this.

Are there any conventions or recommended ways to handle errors that need to contain potentially lots of additional information?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, a concrete example might be helpful. – But note that 1) `enum` can have associated values, 2) an error can be a `struct` or `class` (with properties), it need not be an `enum`.

Comment: I guess if I can use a struct and go with option 2, that is basically the same as a more traditional exception object, and if I define the enum inside that struct it wouldn't be too ugly.

Comment: Specifically I am writing a simple parser and want a place to store the affected line and column numbers (and potentially other information in the future), but without requiring that every handler explicitly add those as associated values.

Comment: What does *"potentially lots of additional information"* mean? A fixed set of properties, or arbitrary information like the `userInfo` dictionary in `NSError`?

Comment: For my purposes it will be a fixed set of properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if there is a "recommended" way, perhaps someone else can 
answer that or provide a better solution.

But one *possible* approach would be to use a `struct` (with properties) as the error type and use optional properties for values which need
not be provided. Example:

```
struct ParserError: Error {
    enum Reason {
        case invalidCharacter
        case unexpectedEOF
    }
    let reason: Reason
    let line: Int?
    let column: Int?

    init(reason: Reason, line: Int? = nil, column: Int? = nil) {
        self.reason = reason
        self.line = line
        self.column = column
    }
}
```

One might also want to adopt the `LocalizedError` protocol to 
provide sensible error descriptions  even if the 
concrete error type is not known by the catcher (compare [How to provide a localized description with an Error type in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176196/how-to-provide-a-localized-description-with-an-error-type-in-swift)):

```
extension ParserError: LocalizedError {
    public var errorDescription: String? {
        var description: String
        switch reason {
        case .invalidCharacter:
            description = "Invalid Character in input file"
        case .unexpectedEOF:
            description = "Unexpected end of file"
        }
        if let line = line {
            description += ", line \(line)"
        }
        if let column = column {
            description += ", column \(column)"
        }
        return description
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
func parse() throws {
    // Throw error with line number, but without column:
    throw ParserError(reason: .invalidCharacter, line: 13)
}

do {
    try parse()
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Output:

```
Invalid Character in input file, line 13
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks! And thanks for the `LocalizedError` tip as well.