# Swift Error Handling and metadata of the error

Tags: swift, swift3

I want to build a fully Swift error handling and propagation system that I can use throughout an entire application. The implementation is fairly straightforward, if you have something like this:

```
enum AnnouncerError: Error {
  /// A network error occured
  case networkError
  /// The program was unable to unwrap data from nil to a non-nil value
  case unwrapError
  /// The parser was unable to validate the XML
  case validationError
  /// The parser was unable to parse the XML
  case parseError
}
```

I can get the type of the error in a delegate function like this using a simple switch statement:

```
func feedFinishedParsing(withFeedArray feedArray: [FeedItem]?, error: AnnouncerError?) {
  // unwrap the error somewhere here
  switch error {
  case .networkError:
    print("Network error occured")
  case .parseError:
    print("Parse error occured")
  case .unwrapError:
    print("Unwrap error occured")
  default:
    print("Unknown error occured")
  }
}
```

However, I have the additional data from a particular case in the error `enum` and that's when the problems arise:

```
enum AnnouncerError: Error {
  /// A network error occured
  case networkError(description: String) //note this line
  /// The program was unable to unwrap data from nil to a non-nil value
  case unwrapError
  /// The parser was unable to validate the XML
  case validationError
  /// The parser was unable to parse the XML
  case parseError
}
```

How should I get the `description` string from the Error type if I call the delegate method with a `.networkError`?

As an extension, if there is no straightforward way to directly get the `description` from a `.networkError`, should I continue using the current architecture where the delegate method has an optional (nullable) Error type where I can check for the type of the error, or should I use a completely different architecture such as a try-catch system and if so, how should I implement it?

Comment: Possibly related: [Swift 3 errors with additional data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41202869/swift-3-errors-with-additional-data) and [How to provide a localized description with an Error type in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176196/how-to-provide-a-localized-description-with-an-error-type-in-swift).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to access the `description` property of `networkError` case , you do not need to do too much.

```
func feedFinishedParsing(withFeedArray feedArray: [FeedItem]?, error: AnnouncerError?) {
    // unwrap the error somewhere here
    switch error {
    // Just declare description in the case, and use it if u need it.
    case .networkError(let description):
        print("Network error occured")
        print(description)
    case .parseError:
        print("Parse error occured")
    case .unwrapError:
        print("Unwrap error occured")
    default:
        print("Unknown error occured")
    }
}
```

Of course, you can build a robust machine for error handling, but if you just wanna access this property, the above solution will do the trick.

Regardless, i would recommend to read further into [Swift pattern matching](https://appventure.me/2015/08/20/swift-pattern-matching-in-detail/), what explains in detail the advanced usage of the `switch` language element is `Swift`.