# What are all types may be used as errors in Swift?

Tags: swift, error-handling

I know Enum is used as below , what about Array or Dictionary?

```
enum VendingMachineError: Error {
  case invalidSelection
  case insufficientFunds(coinsNeeded: Int)
  case outOfStock
  }

throw VendingMachineError.insufficientFunds(coinsNeeded: 5)
```

Comment: Could you clarify the question? "what about Array or Dictionary" what about them?! what do you mean by this?

Comment: I am asking, can we handle errors in swift with String or Array ?

Comment: This was my interview question , I am trying to share this we everyone to know the exact answer . I said no , the only way is Enum but I am not sure.

Comment: Try to give an example (maybe a pseudo-code) to let us what are you asking for/trying to achieve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Any* type conforming to the `Error` protocol can be used. If you really want
to throw an array then it suffices to declare conformance to the protocol:

```
extension Array: Error {}

do {
    throw [1, 2, 3]
} catch {
    print("Failed:", error) // Failed: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Here is more realistic example, using a `struct` to throw
an error with additional information (a simplified example from
[Swift 3 errors with additional data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41202869/swift-3-errors-with-additional-data/41203237#41203237)):

```
struct ParserError: Error, LocalizedError {
    let line: Int

    public var errorDescription: String? {
        return "Parser error at line \(line)"
    }
}

func parse() throws {
    throw ParserError(line: 13)
}

do {
    try parse()
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Output:

```
Parser error at line 13
```

Comment: Is there a purpose of doing this? So, `error` would an array instead of -let's say- enum, correct?

Comment: @AhmadF: Using an array is more a theoretical example, I do not see a real usage for that. I have added a link to a more realistic non-enum example.