# Type does not conform to protocol CustomStringConvertible

Tags: swift, enums, swift3

I'm implementing try catch enum:

```
enum processError: Error, CustomStringConvertible {

        case one
        var localizedDescription: String{
            return "one"
        }
        case two
        var localizedDescription: String {
            return "two"
        }
    }
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> type processError does not conform to protocol CustomStringConvertible

But if I change the name of the variable in the second case I don't get the error:

```
enum processError: Error, CustomStringConvertible {

    case one
    var localizedDescription: String{
        return "one"
    }
    case two
    var description: String {
        return "two"
    }
}
```

My question is why I can not have the same name of the variable for all the cases?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Press ⌘4 and click on the disclosure triangle next to the error. You will see: *Protocol requires property `description`...* and you cannot declare a variable with the same name twice (*Invalid redeclaration...* error)

Comment: Possibly related: [How to provide a localized description with an Error type in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176196/how-to-provide-a-localized-description-with-an-error-type-in-swift).

Comment: @user2924482 `enum ProcessError: String, Error {
    case one, two
    var description: String {
        return rawValue
    }
}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that the `CustomStringConvertible` protocol requires one property:

```
var description: String
```

You need to have the `description` property or you will get the error that it doesn't conform to the protocol.

I also suggest this approach:

```
enum processError: Error, CustomStringConvertible {
    case one
    case two

    var description: String {
        switch self {
            case .one:
                return "one"
            case .two:
                return "two"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Overriding localizedDescription does not work that way (unless you cast an Error to the specific processError), compare above link under the question.

Comment: @MartinR Thank. I removed that part of the answer. I'll leave it focused on the protocol issue.