# Custom Error type initializer

Tags: swift

Let me prefix with why I think this is not a duplicate of [How to provide a localized description with an Error type in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176196)

The answers provided will still result in some static/class function call and not an initializer style or require casting to NSError (which I like to avoid).

---

A brief summery of the reasons:

A Swift function that `throws` does not declare the error **type**. We cannot enforce the `catch` to pass a custom type that simply conforms to the `Error` protocol. Knowing that, on the do-catch side, we get no help from the compiler as to what type (if custom) of error we get and by default we'll expect the known `NSError` properties. Otherwise, we need to simply rely on textual documentations explaining the type of errors we can catch, as the catch will simply pass an `Error` type.

Now, unlike NSError, Error is a protocol where the properties we get in `userInfo` are read only. So we resort to constructing an NSError type, and casting it as Error.

---

I am trying to create a simple clean struct that return an Error type (not NSError) where I can throw like:

```
throw MYError(domain: "com.somthing.error", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "Something bad happened"])
```

Main issue is that the only way to set the `NSLocalizedDescriptionKey`, is by initializing an NSError object. Doing so will require casting to `Error` type (which is something I'm trying to avoid).

I first tried to use `extension Error {...`, but cannot use an initializer.

If I use a struct conforming to Error protocol (`struct MyError: Error {...`), I still have the problem of `localizedDescription` is get only.

What I use is actually something like:

```
struct MYError: Error {

    static func with(domain: String = "com.somthing.error", code: Int = 0, localizedDescription: String) -> Error {
        return NSError(domain: domain, code: code, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : localizedDescription]) as Error
    }
}
```

Which I can use like:

```
throw MYError.with(localizedDescription: "Some Error has happened")
```

Intuitively, I would expect a type like `MYError` to just use an initializer `MYError(domain:...`, not a static function.

---

The more Swifty way would be something like:

```
enum ErrorType: Error {
    case one
    case two
    case three(with: String)
}

...

// In some function:
throw ErrorThrown.three(with: "Three!")

...

// Catch like:
catch ErrorType.three(let str) {
    print("Error three: \(str)")
}
```

---

It is not clear if we're there yet. It seems that NSError is still much at play where I know I can expect to get a `localizedDescription` an optional `localizedFailureReason` and the familiar NSError properties.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to provide a localized description with an Error type in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176196/how-to-provide-a-localized-description-with-an-error-type-in-swift)

Comment: @Coder256 Not exactly a duplicate. I read that one, not talking about localizing, I am talking about an initializer.

Comment: `Error` is just a protocol, so you can't initialize it.  Read: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html

Comment: If you want to always include the same localized description for every unique error, then just do `throw MyError.customError` in that link for example. There is no need to initialize it. However, if you want to include a dynamic message (or different message for the same error), you probably should just include that in the `userInfo`, but you could use an [associated value](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID148).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Similarly as in [How to provide a localized description with an Error type in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176196/how-to-provide-a-localized-description-with-an-error-type-in-swift)
you can define a custom error type adopting the  `LocalizedError`
protocol:

```
public struct MyError: Error {
    let msg: String

}

extension MyError: LocalizedError {
    public var errorDescription: String? {
            return NSLocalizedString(msg, comment: "")
    }
}
```

Example:

```
do {
    throw MyError(msg: "Something happened")
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

This prints the localized version of the given message.
Note that `error` in the catch-clause is a general `Error`, so
the caller does not need to cast it to the concrete error type (or even know
which error type is thrown).

Comment: I was trying to avoid using a static function. A static function `MyError.customError` is what I am using (in a different way).

Comment: @bauerMusic: Perhaps I misunderstood your question. Is the updated answer what you are looking for?

Comment: Good answer, the only issue is the need for casting (error as! MYError) to access the localizedDescription.

Comment: @bauerMusic: No. As I pointed out, there is *no need* to cast the error to MyError in the catch clause. Did you try the above example? Please let me know if it does not work.

Comment: I get `The operation couldn’t be completed. (ExeptionsInSwift.MyError error 1.)` when I try to access `localizedDescription`

Comment: @bauerMusic: Strange, I tested the my code with Swift 3 and 4 on macOS with Xcode 8.3.3. and 9, and it works as expected. What platform are you on?

Comment: I tested it on a 'Command Line Tool' App. Could be an issue there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146721/discussion-between-martin-r-and-bauermusic).

Comment: Summery points: `var errorDescription` is what return in `localizedDescription`. In the `catch let error`, the `let error` can be omitted.

Comment: @bauerMusic: Yes, but I prefer to write `let error` explicitly, so that the reader of the code does not have to "know" or "guess" where it comes from. Similarly for `didSet` and `willSet` which have "automatic" parameters oldValue/newValue. – Surely a matter of personal preference!

Answer (score 7):

`Error` is a protocol, you can *throw* anything which conforms to that protocol

For example

```
struct MYError : Error {
    let description : String
    let domain : String

    var localizedDescription: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(description, comment: "")
    }
}
```

And you can use it:

```
func test() throws
{
  throw MYError(description: "Some Error has happened", domain: "com.somthing.error")
}
```

---

```
do {
    try test()
} catch let error as MYError{
    print("error: ", error.domain, error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Good answer, the only issue is the need for casting (error as MYError).

Comment: Consider the ability to throw many many kinds of `Error` conforming errors.

Answer (score 2):

Finally found a way to stick anything in a generic Error type.
Thanks to **vadian** and **Martin R**, on which answers I finally came to this part.

Comes down to this:

```
struct MyError: Error {

    var locString: String
    var reason: String?
    var code: Int
    var wish: String
}

// The errorDescription is the only part that actually comes generically with Error
extension MyError: LocalizedError {

    // This is actually part of LocalizedError
    var errorDescription: String? {
        return locString
    }
}

extension Error {

    var errorCode: Int {
        return (self as! MyError).code
    }

    var failureReason: String? {
        return (self as! MyError).reason
    }

    var everythingYouWishFor: String {
        return (self as! MyError).wish
    }
}

...

throw MyError(locString: "Localized string", reason: "The reason", code: 12, wish: "Best wishes")
```

Comment: Very nice.  Thank you.  