# Declaring property in extension and getting bad access error

Tags: ios, swift

I stuck into an issue where I want to declare a property in NSError extension.
This is my error structure

```
struct CustomError {
   var errorTitle: String?
   var errorDescription: String?
   var isClear: Bool?
}
```

This is my extension

```
extension NSError {
var customeError:CustomError {
    get {
        return self.customeError
    }

    set {
        self.customeError = newValue
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting bad access error while setting custom error into the property.

Comment: Both `get` and `set` call themselves recursively. What are you trying to achieve? Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39176196/1187415 ?

Comment: Yes, that's why it was creating retain cycle. Now in updated question there will be no retain cycle and it is working like charm :)

Comment: If you have a solution then post it as an *answer,* not as an update to your question.

Comment: @MartinR thanks for your suggestion I posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add properties to `extensions`.

There only way to make it work is to use `objc_getAssociatedObject` to have stored properties.

Answer (score 0):

After searching this issue over the internet I found a cool solution. We can declare but there is the trick here is the updated extension.

```
extension NSError {
  struct Holder {
      static var customErr: CustomError = CustomError()
  }
  var customeError:CustomError {
      get {
          return Holder.customErr
      }

      set {
          Holder.customErr = newValue
      }
  }
}
```

Actually previously in the question which I posted there was retain cycle but when I added holder then there is no cycle and code working perfectly.

Thanks, guys

Comment: It was “infinite recursion“, not a “retain cycle.” – It is still unclear to me what you actually want to achieve. With your solution, all `NSError` instances share the same `customErr`.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinR for clear this to me. Actually, there are some more properties which I am getting from the server, I need to parse that error into my model and perform some action accordingly.