# What should I print when catch an error in swift?

Tags: swift

```
catch let error {
    print(error)
    print("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Prints:

> typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath:
>   [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription:
>   "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.",
>   underlyingError: nil))
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

As for me information

> debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary
>   instead."

is much more useful than text in `error.localizedDescription`.
So why can't I do something like this:
`print(error.debugDescription)`
It doesn't compile.

Comment: Why do you think you should print anything?

Comment: You can `print((error as NSError).debugDescription)`. But why wouldn’t you just `print(error)` or `debugPrint(error)`?

Comment: You can use `catch DecodingError.typeMismatch(...)` instead, etc to handle them: `} catch DecodingError.dataCorrupted(let context) { print(context) } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch(let type, let context) { print(type); print(context) } catch { print("Default: \(error)") }`

Answer (score 1):

debugDescription is defined in the protocol CustomDebugStringConvertible. So you would have to cast error first:

```
if let customDebugStringConvertible = error as? CustomDebugStingConvertible {
    print(customerDebugStringConvertible.debugDescription)
}
```

As for what to print. The most informative version for logging is is to simply print(error).

Answer (score 1):

You can give your errors descriptions!

```
enum MyErrors: String, Error {
   case badError = "I think it went wrong here"
   case evilError = "This should have never happened"
}

func test() throws {
   if Bool.random() {
      throw MyErrors.badError
   } else {
      throw MyErrors.evilError
   }
}

do {
   try test()
} catch let error {
    if let myError = error as? MyErrors {
        print(myError.rawValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: This requires the caller to know (and cast to) the actual error type. For an alternative solution see https://stackoverflow.com/q/39176196/1187415

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the catch (no pun intended) I'll update my answer right now