# How to get the string I put into a Error instance?

Tags: swift, error-handling

Basicly I got this,

```swift
// MyPackage.swift

enum Error: LocalizedError {
    case general(String)
}

func foobar() throws {
    throw Error.general("haha")
}

do {
    try foobar()
} catch Error.general(let message) {
    // will print "haha"
    print(message)
}
```

And then in the unit test, I need to check if I got the exact same error,

```swift
import Quick
import Nimble
import MyPackage

class MySpec: QuickSpec {
    
    override func spec() {
        describe("") {
            let input = "haha"
            let count = 2
            let expectation = Error.general("非纯数字字符串无法使用本方法")
            
            context("输入_" + input) {
                it("预期_" + expectation.localizedDescription) {
                    // got the error
                    // but expectation.localizedDescription was not what I looking for
                    expect(try numberStringByAddingZerosInto(input, tillReach: count))
                        .to(throwError(expectation))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It worked, but expectation.localizedDescription was not "haha", which made the name of the test case useless.
I also tried expectation.errorDescription with no luck.

Where could I get it?
And why is it like this?

Comment: Possibly helpful: [How to provide a localized description with an Error type in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39176196/1187415)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

override `errorDescription` var

```
enum Error: LocalizedError {
    case general(String)
    
    var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {
        case .general(let errorMessage):
            return errorMessage
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you can also write do-catch block by this

```
do {
    try foobar()
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```