# Swift Handling Custom Error but something wrong

Tags: swift, error-handling

This is my custom error

```
public struct CSHttpError: Error {
    
    enum CSHttpErrorScene {
        case clientRequestError
        case customError
    }
    
    let code: Int?
    let kind: CSHttpErrorScene
    let description: String?
    
    init(code:Int?,kind:CSHttpErrorScene,description:String?) {
        self.code = code
        self.kind = kind
        self.description = description ?? ""
    }
}
```

when post request and get a null data
i want to throw this error with CSHttpError

```
let error = CSHttpError(code: -1, kind: .clientRequestError, description:"No Response Data")
throw error
```

but when I catch this error "description" and "code" are missing

```
...
} catch let error as CSHttpError {
 print(error.description) // Optional("The operation couldn’t be completed. (VHK.CSHttpError error 1.)")
 print(error.kind) // .clientRequestError
 throw VHKError.network(error)
}
```

error.description should be "No Response Data" ????

I try to debug it, but it does not work

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39176196/1187415

Comment: This is not reproducible in an Xcode playground