# Enum with instance-variable? (in Swift)

Tags: swift, enums, nserror

I define all custom Errors using `enum`(s), like:

```
public enum MyErrorEnum: String, LocalizedError {
    case FileNotFound = "Failed to find file."

    public var errorDescription: String? { rawValue }
}
```

But some errors require additional `context`, like adding file-path to the message.

Unfortunately, because Swift enums don't support instance variables, **I tried workarounds, like:**

```
private var KEY_CONTEXT: UInt8 = 0;

public enum MyErrorEnum: String, LocalizedError {
    case FileNotFound = "Failed to find file."

    public var errorDescription: String? { rawValue }

    public var context: String {
        return objc_getAssociatedObject(self as NSObject, &KEY_CONTEXT)
            as? String ?? "";
    }

    @discardableResult
    public mutating func withContext(_ value: String) -> Self {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(
            self as NSObject, &KEY_CONTEXT, value as NSString,
            .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
        return self;
    }
}
```

> **Note** that above does not raise any compile and/or runtime error in **Xcode 12**, but just did not work.
>
> And later, I was notified that **Xcode 13** raises compile error below:
> "`Cannot convert value of type 'MyErrorEnum' to type 'NSObject' in coercion`"

I also already tried simply changing `String` to a custom `StringWithContext` class which implements `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`, but NOT even that did work (probably because enum's `rawValue` is somehow change protected).

#### Is there any way to add additional variable to said enum?

Comment: Now with a little more context than your previous question, it doesn't look like enums are suitable for this use case at all. Use a struct with two properties - `context` and `errorType`, where `errorType` is a simple enum. If each case is associated with different types of contexts however, consider using [associated values](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID148).

Comment: @Sweeper the problem is clean throwing and catching without rethrow and copy/paste need. **Firstly,** I want messages without copy/pasting (`enum` is pretty unique without copy/pasting), but somehow need to have variable context/details. **Secondly,** I want to be able to `catch` each `case` separately, NOT catching entire `struct` then doing `switch` inside the `catch`, and want to avoid forgeting to rethrow cases we don't handle.

Answer (score -1):

**No**, currently there is no way to add instance variable to `enum` directly in `Swift`.

(in `Java` that's trivial, as there `enum` is yet another `class`).

However, if you insist on using Swift's `enum`, use associative-enum with default value as message.

### Example

Simply, copy and add `LocalizedErrorEnum` from below into your project once, and reuse as many times as required with associative-enums.

```
public protocol LocalizedErrorEnum: LocalizedError {
    var errorDescription: String? { get }
}

extension LocalizedErrorEnum {
    public var errorDescription: String? {
        if let current = Mirror(reflecting: self).children.first {
            let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: current.value);
            // Initial error description.
            let message = mirror.children.first?.value as? String
                ?? current.label ?? "Unknown-case";
            var context = "";
            // Iterate additional context.
            var i = 0;
            for associated in mirror.children {
                if i >= 1 {
                    if let text = associated.value as? String {
                        context += "\n  ";
                        if let label: String = associated.label {
                            context += "\(label): "
                        }
                        context += text;
                    }
                }
                i += 1;
            }
            return context.isEmpty ? message : (
                message + " {" + context + "\n}"
            );
        }
        return "\(self)";
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```swift
public enum MyErrorEnum: LocalizedErrorEnum {
    case FileNotFound(String = "Failed to find file.", file: String)
}

// ...

do {
    let path = "/path/to/file.txt";
    throw MyErrorEnum.FileNotFound(
        file: path
    );
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Failed to find file. {
  file: /path/to/file.txt
}
```

See also:
[Simplest way to throw custom error in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68091816/8740349)